# Removing apostrophes in list

Tags: python, string, list, integer

how to remove apostrophes in list like below:

```
x = [['3.937', '1.968', '1.968'], ['3.937', '1.968', '1.968'], ['3.937', '1.968', '1.968'], ['7.874', '3.937', '1.968'], ['7.874', '3.937', '1.968'], ['7.874', '3.937', '1.968'], ['7.874', '3.937', '1.968'], ['7.874', '3.937', '1.968'], ['7.874', '3.937', '1.968']]
```

All in all i want to convert this thing to like this:

```
x = [(3.937,1.968,1.968),(3.937,1.968,1.968)]

result = int(my_list[0])
```

but there is errors like :
result = int(x[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
result = int(x[0])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'
```

Comment: Why do you turn a list of list to a list of tuples ? And why do you use the int conversion for reals ?

Comment: There seem to be fewer elements in your output list than in the input list. Is that intended?

Comment: And you seem to want to have floats, why did you attempt to use `int`?

Comment: Actually all i want to do is, remove apostrophes and convert like ''' x = [(3.937,1.968,1.968),(3.937,1.968,1.968)]'''

Comment: @Stuart no, it just for example.

Comment: ```result = int(x[0][0])```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a nested list. If you use `int(x[0])` you are accessing the first sublist: `['3.937','1.968','1.968']` which can't be transformed via `int()`, therefore you need to use a nested list-comprehension approach:

```
result = [[float(value) for value in sublist] for sublist in x]
```

If you'd like to have tuples instead of nested-list, you can use:

```
result = [tuple([float(value) for value in sublist]) for sublist in x]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehensions with `map` on every sub list

```
x = [list(map(float, y)) for y in x]
```

Answer (score 2):

The apostrophes show that the values are strings. Each string seems to be a representation of a float. Therefore:

```
x = [['3.937', '1.968', '1.968'], ['3.937', '1.968', '1.968'], ['3.937', '1.968', '1.968'], ['7.874', '3.937', '1.968'], ['7.874', '3.937', '1.968'], ['7.874', '3.937', '1.968'], ['7.874', '3.937', '1.968'], ['7.874', '3.937', '1.968'], ['7.874', '3.937', '1.968']]

x = [tuple(map(float, e)) for e in x]

print(x)
```

**Output:**

```
[(3.937, 1.968, 1.968), (3.937, 1.968, 1.968), (3.937, 1.968, 1.968), (7.874, 3.937, 1.968), (7.874, 3.937, 1.968), (7.874, 3.937, 1.968), (7.874, 3.937, 1.968), (7.874, 3.937, 1.968), (7.874, 3.937, 1.968)]
```